# Angular Factory Local Variables

Tags: angularjs

This question has probably  something to do with me not grasping the factory concept in angular, i have the following factory:

```
.factory('utils', ['api', '$log', '$q',
    function(api, $log, $q) {

    var utils = {};
    var cart = {
        products: new Array(),
        payment: 'cash'
    };


    /**
     * Access the shopping cart
     */
    utils.getCart = function() {
        return this.cart;

    };


    return utils;

}
]);
```

The problem is that the local variable *cart* is not persistent, when i try to access the factory from the controller *cart* is always undefined. I understand that *this.cart* refer to a field in the util object which is not the case, but how can i return the local variable.

Comment: `return cart;` should do it.

Comment: @MattWay I am doing exactly that and it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use 'this' keyword into your code block

```
utils.getCart = function() {
    return cart;
};
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a matter of the concept of '`this`' in Javascript and how it works.  When you invoke `getCart`, 'this' refers to the object the function was invoked on, so in your case '`this`' should refer to the `utils` object and since `cart` doesn't exist on that object, its undefined.

Change your return in `getCart` to simply return '`cart`' since that will return the private variable `cart` defined inside the function factory.

Some good reading on the subject:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 0):

getCart() method here would get its own scope, so 'this' keyword would refer to local variable within scope of getCart() function.
To return Cart , please define a parent scope pointer : var parent=this ; (to point to scope within factory) as a sibling to utils
and then within function getCart(), return like this : return parent.cart;